# Creating Ldap Plug ii Grails 2.3

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm trying to move my project from Grails 2.2.4 to Grails 2.3.5, and I need some plugins, one of them is Ldap's. To access to my repository I have an URL:

```
grailsRepo "http:// svn................"
```

and my dependency resolver is maven

an Y have this code after:

```
plugins {
    // plugins for the build system only
    build ":tomcat:7.0.50"

    // plugins for the compile step
    compile ":scaffolding:2.0.1"
    compile ':cache:1.1.1'

    // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
    runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.7"// or ":hibernate4:4.1.11.6" or hibernate:3.6.10.7
    runtime ":database-migration:1.3.8"
    runtime ":jquery:1.10.2.2"
    runtime ":resources:1.2.1"
    compile ":ldap:0.8.3.2"
}
```

and I got the next error

```
The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.grails.plugins:ldap:zip:0.8.3.2, org.grails.plugins:spring-security-ldap-dcas:zip:1.0.6: Could not find artifact org.grails.plugins:ldap:zip:0.8.3.2 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins)
```

|Run 'grails dependency-report' for further information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the latest version of the ldap plugin is 0.8.2 - see http://grails.org/plugin/ldap

If this is a custom build that's in your local repo, try switching to the ivy resolver